# bootstrap : validating form fields with file attachment and redirect to same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, twitter-bootstrap

So i've been working on this for days and done lots of research over internet with no sucess, so i'm giving a try to understand if anyone can help me.

I've this form :

```
<!-- Modal form contactjobApply starts -->

<div class="modal hide fade" id="contactformjobapply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactformLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/bt_close_form.png"></button>
                <h1 class="modal-title" id="contactformLabel">NOUS CONTACTER POUR :</h1>
                <p class="forminformation">Sécrétaire réceptionniste français anglais</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="formmail_apply.php" autocomplete="on">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Postulation à l'offre d'emploi">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="textinputprenom">Prénom*</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="textinputprenom" name="formpnom" type="text" placeholder="Votre prénom" required autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="textinputnom">Nom*</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="textinputnom" name="formnom" type="text" placeholder="Votre Nom">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="textinputmail">Adresse e-mail*</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="textinputmail" name="formmail" type="email" placeholder="Votre adresse e-mail" required title="Un adresse e-mail valid. Ex:. moi@gmail.com">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="textinputcontact">Téléphone*</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="textinputcontact" name="formcontact" type="tel" placeholder="Votre contact par téléphone ou natel" maxlength="10" pattern="[10|0][0-9]{9}" required title="Votre nº de téléphone. Ex:. 0781231212 ou 0221231212">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="textinputprofession">Profession*</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="textinputprofession" name="formprofession" type="text" placeholder="Votre profession actuelle" required>
                            </div>
                        <div class="control-group fileupload">
                            <label class="control-label" for="filebutton">Votre dossier*</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <a class="file-input-wrapper btinput">CHOISIR FICHIER
                                <p class="help-block2">Pas de fichier téléchargé</p>
                                    <input id="filebutton" type="file" title="Choisir votre CV" name="filebutton" accept="text/plain,application/pdf,application/msword,application/rtf" allow="text/plain,application/pdf,application/msword,application/rtf" required placeholder="Pas de fichier téléchargé">
                                </a>
                                <p class="help-block">NB: Envoyez uniquement des fichiers au format DOC / PDF / TXT - 1Mo MAX</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="textarea" required>Lettre de motivation*</label>
                            <div class="controls">                     
                                <textarea id="textarea" name="formmessage" placeholder="Votre lettre de motivation" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="bt_sendform">ENVOYER</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal form contactjobApply ends -->
```

And this PHP :

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
    // Pear library includes
    // You should have the pear lib installed
    include_once('Mail.php');
    include_once('Mail_Mime/mime.php');
    // infos from form
    $email_to = "your@mail.com";
    $email_subject = "Nouveau message d'yourwebsite.com";
    $upload_folder = './uploads/'; //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script
   // Check for safari
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "Vos informations ne sont pas correctes<br><br><br>";
        echo "Remplissez les champs suivants :<br><br>";
        echo $error."<br><br>";
        echo "Remplissez les champs en manque<br><br>";
        die();
    }
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['formpnom']) ||
        !isset($_POST['formnom']) ||
        !isset($_POST['formmail']) ||
        !isset($_POST['formcontact']) ||
        !isset($_POST['formprofession']) ||
        !isset($_POST['formmessage'])) {
            died('Il semble manquer des informations');
        }
    //Get the uploaded file information
    $name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['filebutton']['name']);
    //get the file extension of the file
    $type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file,
               strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);
    $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["filebutton"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs
    //Settings
    $max_allowed_file_size = 1024; // size in KB
    $allowed_extensions = array("txt", "doc", "docx", "pdf");
    //Validations
    if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size ) {
        $error_message .= "\n La taille du fichier doit être plus petite";
    }
    //------ Validate the file extension -----
    $allowed_ext = false;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++) {
        if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0) {
            $allowed_ext = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$allowed_ext) {
        $error_message .= "\n Ce fichier n'est pas valable. ".
            " Télécharger uniquement les fichiers suivants : ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
    }
    //copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder
    $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
    $tmp_path = $_FILES["filebutton"]["tmp_name"];
    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path)) {
        if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file)) {
            $error_message .= "\n Votre fichier n'est pas attaché, un problème est la cause";
        }
    }
    // declare variables
    $first_name = $_POST['formpnom']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['formnom']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['formmail']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['formcontact']; // required
    $profession = $_POST['formprofession']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['formmessage']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    // Check for safari
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'Un adresse e-mail valid. Ex:. moi@gmail.com<br>';
    }
    $phone_exp = '/^[10|0][0-9]{9}$/';
    if(!preg_match($phone_exp,$telephone)) {
        $error_message .= 'Votre nº de téléphone. Ex:. 0781231212 ou 0221231212<br>';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-zÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÕÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜŸŒÆàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿœæ  .'-]+$/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= "Votre prénom n'est pas valide<br>";
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= "Votre nom n'est pas valide<br>";
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$profession)) {
        $error_message .= "Votre profession n'est pas valide<br>";
    }
    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= "Vous n'avez pas de message<br>";
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    // Message before mail
    $email_message .= "Prénom : ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Nom : ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Adresse e-mail: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Téléphone : ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Profession : ".clean_string($profession)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message : ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
    // create email headers
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    header("Location: http://bpoeta.net/pen/anj");
    //send the email
    $message = new Mail_mime(); 
    $message->setTXTBody($email_message); 
    $message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);
    $body = $message->get();
    $extraheaders = array("From"=>$email_to, "Subject"=>$email_subject,"Reply-To"=>$email_from);
    $headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
    $mail = Mail::factory("mail");
    $mail->send($email_to, $headers, $body);
    //redirect to 'thank-you page
    header('Location: http://bpoeta.net/pen/anj');
?>
```

I've been able to make it work with input validation, and sending back to my chosen link after a sent mail, but sundenly it stop work and I can't achieve how to attach a file to a mail and send it with the mail.

I've been using bootstrap for most configurations and I would like to be able, if possible, after sending the email, to keep in the modal layer of the form, with an alert message, or send it back to the index page. and of course be able to send a file attached with the email.

I would really appreciate your help on this

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You really need to learn to narrow down your problem. It will help you solve it yourself, and it will make it possible for someone else to help you. Nobody is going to read all of that code to try to figure out where your problem is, and _then_ to try to solve it for you.

Comment: The point is to try to understand something new, and if you have a place where people can help you clarify the way great.
When you expose a problem, if you omit some facts, your solution is worthless, and comments with no meaning are useful as that too. So if you wish to help it's ok, if don't step on your way!
I i like to thank for any help received!
Merry holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
    // files sent
    if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
        // define allowed extensions
        $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","txt");
        $files = array();
        $maxsize = 1048576;
        // loop through all the files
        foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
            // define variables
            $file_name = $file['name']; 
            $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
            // check file allow
            $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
            $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
            $sizeu = filesize($file);
            $fsize = $file['size'];
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
                die("Le fichier $file_name a le format $ext qui n'est pas autorisé ou aucun fichier a été uploader.<br><br>Retournez à la page précédente");
            }
            if(($fsize >= $maxsize) || ($fsize == 0)) {
                die("Le fichier $file_name est de $fsize Mo .<br><br>Sa taille ne doit pas dépasser 1 Mo.<br><br>Retournez à la page précédente");
            }
            // move the file to server        
            $server_file = "$path_parts[basename]";
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $server_file);
            // add file to arrays       
            array_push($files,$server_file);
        }
        // Check for safari
        function died($error) {
            // your error code can go here
            echo "Vos informations ne sont pas correctes<br><br><br>";
            echo "Remplissez les champs suivants :<br><br>";
            echo $error."<br><br>";
            echo "Remplissez les champs en manque<br><br>";
            die();
        }
        // validation expected data exists
        if(!isset($_POST['formnom']) ||
           !isset($_POST['formmail']) ||
           !isset($_POST['formsubject']) ||
           !isset($_POST['formmessage'])) {
            died('Il semble manquer des informations');
        }
        // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
        $name = $_POST['formnom']; // required
        $to = "your@mail.com";
        $email_fromto = "no-reply@mail.com";
        $from = $_POST['formmail'];
        $subject = "E-mail envoyé de yourwebsite.com";
        $formsubject = $_POST['formsubject']; // required
        $msg = $_POST['formmessage'];
        $error_message = "";
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_fromto."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();     
        // Check for safari
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$from)) {
            $error_message .= 'Un adresse e-mail valid. Ex:. moi@gmail.com<br>';
        }
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-zÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÕÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜŸŒÆàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿœæ  .'-]+$/";
        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
            $error_message .= "Votre nom n'est pas valide<br>";
        }
        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$formsubject)) {
            $error_message .= "Votre objet n'est pas valide<br>";
        }
        if(strlen($msg) < 2) {
            $error_message .= "Vous n'avez pas de message<br>";
        }
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($error_message);
        }
        // Message before mail
        $mail_message = "Contenu de ce message\n\n";
        function clean_string($string) {
            $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
            return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }
        $mail_message .= "Nom : ".clean_string($name)."\n";
        $mail_message .= "Adresse e-mail: ".clean_string($from)."\n";
        $mail_message .= "Objet : ".clean_string($formsubject)."\n";
        $mail_message .= "Message : ".clean_string($msg)."\n";
        // boundary
        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        // headers boundary
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
        $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        // headers plain
        $message ="\n\n--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $message .="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
        $message .="Content-Transfer-Enconding: 7bit\n\n" . $mail_message . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        // loop
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $aFile = fopen($file,"rb");
            $data = fread($aFile,filesize($file));
            fclose($aFile);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n";
            $message .= " name=\"$file\"\n";
            $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n";
            $message .= " filename=\"$file\"\n";
            $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        }
        // send  
        $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
        if ($ok) { 
            echo '
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.location = "http://yourwebsite.com"
                </script>
                '; 
        } else { 
            echo "<p>Votre e-mail n'a pas été envoyé, un problème dans votre terminal l'empêche</p>"; 
        }
        die();
    }
?>
```

and for the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="formmail.php" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Thanks a lot for the guys who helped me :)
It's hard to understand php when you're not good on math, and you only into webdesign (I mean design).

Cheers all and hope it helps others!